# Why there is no recursive enumerable set such as B that: > $B \nleq_m K$?

Tags: logic, computability

I get stuck in one fact that I see on old-mid exam.

Why there is no recursive enumerable set such as B that:

> $B \nleq_m K$

Def: `K` means Halting Set and $ \leq_m$ means many-one reducible.

anyone could hint or idea for me?

Answer (score 2):

The full result is actually a little stronger: For any set $A$, $A'$ is $1$-complete for the r.e. sets in $A$.

To see it for $K (= \varnothing')$. We need to define a $1-1$ recursive function $f$ so that $x \in W_e$ iff $f(x) \in K$. Yet, $x \in W_e$ iff $\varphi_e(x)\downarrow$. By the s-n-m theorem, there is a recursive 1-1 function $k(x)$, so that $\varphi_e(x) = \varphi_{k(x)}(k(x))$ (intuitively, $k$ takes an $x$ and returns an index for a program that simulates $\varphi_e(x)$).

But then, $x \in W_e$ iff $\varphi_e(x)\downarrow$ iff $\varphi_{k(x)}(k(x))\downarrow$ iff $k(x) \in K$.

You can easily relativize this to arbitrary oracle, and, make the reduction uniform in $e$ if you like.

Comment: can I ask a question? you say there is no recursive enumerable set such as B that:  $B \nleq_m K$. @am I Right?

Comment: No, that is what you said. I proved something even stronger.

Comment: +1, I means as a result there is no recursive enumerable with that condition, now is it right?

Comment: can I talk you in a chat?

Comment: can I say there is no r.e set that $B \leq_1 K$? is it right now?

Comment: what is the full result in one sentence? would you please say it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that for any recursively enumerable language, you can create a many-one reduction to $K$. Since you are only given that the language is r.e., clearly any proof will have to make use of that fact. In other words, provide a mapping reduction that makes use of the recognizer of the language you're reducing from.

Comment: can I ask one question ?

Comment: Sure. I'm guessing this is for a homework assignment?

Comment: Really not, there is no homework, I ran into some facts about computation, can I talk to you in a chat?